# Problem with collisions between static and moveable objects with non rectangular outline

Tags: phaser-framework

As part of work I was told to build a small game in phaser where I have to drag and drop some objects using mouse over some static objects in the scene and make out if the drop was done on the matching static object. The static and the not static objects all have non-rectangular boundaries, so I used Physics editor to draw their boundaries and import them into Phaser. To detect collisions while dragging the object I am using matter callbacks for 'collisionstart' and 'collisionend'. Say for example I am trying to drag an apple onto a tree, as soon as the the apple body collides with the tree outline, 'collisionstart' triggers, but as I move the apple inside the tree boundary 'collisionstart' and 'collisionend' trigger multiple times. So this seems to be an unreliable way to detect overlap between two objects.

Collision code:

```
            var canDrag = this.matter.world.nextGroup();
            currentObject = this.matter.add.image(360, 360, 'Carrot', 0, { chamfer: 16 }).setCollisionGroup(canDrag);
            currentObject.body.label = 'Carrot';
            this.matter.add.mouseSpring({ collisionFilter: { group: canDrag } });

            this.matter.world.on('collisionstart', function (event, bodyA, bodyB)
            {
                if ((bodyA.parent.label == 'Tree') || (bodyB.parent.label == 'Tree')) {
                    tree.tint = tintColor;
                }
            });
            this.matter.world.on('collisionend', function (event, bodyA, bodyB)
            {
                if ((bodyA.parent.label == 'Tree') || (bodyB.parent.label == 'Tree')) {
                    tree.tint = normalColor;
                }
            });
```

Comment: Hi Jasmeet! Can you provide your Phaser config object as well as the code for your collision events? A codepen illustrating your issue would also be helpful. It will be much easier to help you if we can see exactly what's going wrong.

Comment: My config:

export default
{
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    scale:
    {
        mode: Phaser.Scale.FIT,
        autoCenter: Phaser.Scale.CENTER_BOTH,
        width: 720,
        height: 720
    },
    physics:
    {
        default: "matter",
        matter:
        {
            gravity:
            {
                x: 0,
                y: 0
            },
            debug: true
        }
    }
};

Comment: As I drag the currentobject over the tree it gets tinted and then loses its tint because of 'collisionend' triggering although my object is inside the tree boundary.